# Add Required Validator on Dynamic Asp:net Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, requiredfieldvalidator

I want to add some Required Validator on Controls(Textbox as example) in a dynamic asp:table.

Code:

```
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> o in Collection)
    {
        TableRow Row = new TableRow();

        TableCell valueCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell Cell = new TableCell();
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtBox1 = new TextBox();


        txtBox1.ID = o.Key + o.Value;
                if (o.Value.Contains("Mandatory"))
                {
                    RequiredFieldValidator req = new RequiredFieldValidator();

                    req.ErrorMessage = "Required";
                    req.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    req.ControlToValidate = txtBox1.ID;
                    req.Enabled = true;
                    req.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;

                    Cell.Controls.Add(req);
                }

        valueCell.Controls.Add(txtBox1);
        Row.Cells.Add(valueCell);
        Row.Cells.Add(Cell);
        table.Rows.Add(Row);
}
```

But i am getting this error:

> " System.Web.UnhandledException in System.web.dll"

on the line `Row.Cells.Add(Cell);`

Can you help me ?

Comment: Please provide the details of the exception - message at least.

Comment: How can i got some details about this exception ? because VS don't open a standard Exception windows .

Comment: As a quick solution, you could wrap the code in a `try / catch` block and put a breakpoint in the `catch` block.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' in System.Web.dll

Internal error in the expression evaluator.

This line causes the error:
Row.Cells.Add(Cell);

Comment: I suspect you are breaking the table structure. The Cells in "table", matches with the cells you add to the new Row added?

Comment: @NicolasRoche please add the code where the exception occurs to your question.

Comment: Table is just an empty <asp:Table><asp:Table> element inside my aspx file. My code use a Dictionnary<string><string> in order to create a textbox for all Values. In order to fill the table structure i use TableCell which contains Textbox, and i add all the TableCell inside TableRow.

Comment: This only happens during dubugging?

Comment: It happens with release too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem with a Panel which contains the Texbox and the RequireValidatorField.

```
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Controls.Add(txtBox1);
    p.Controls.Add(req);
    valueCell.Controls.Add(p);
```